# .htaccess redirect with multiple rewrites

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect a few select pages to HTTPS. I have found numerous examples but they do not seem to work with whats in my current htaccess file. My current htaccess has

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
# Redirect all other domains to the primary
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.?|)(domain1\.com|domain2\.com|domain3\.com|\.co)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.prefferreddomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# Error Documents
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
#Cache Settings, etc. after this
```

I am doing this currently in my htaccess file for SEO as we own several domain names (20+). Anyway I want 3 pages to redirect to HTTPS but all the examples I have tried did not work as expected. I am not sure if I should put them before or after the redirect that is currently in the htaccess file.

The pages that should be redirected to https are logon.php & chat.php. So I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (logon.php)
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.preferreddomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (chats.php)
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.preferreddomain.com%{REQUEST_URI}

# Redirect all other domains to the primary
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.?|)(domain1\.com|domain2\.com|domain3\.com|\.co)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.prefferreddomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# Error Documents
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
#Cache Settings, etc. after this
```

But this did not work. Does anyone have any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Add `[R=301,L]` to the end of each of the https:// rules. Without the `L`, the rule flags the URI as a redirect, but the URI continues through the rest of the rewrite engine and will match against the last rule as well.

Comment: This resulted in a strange redirect url like "https://www.preferreddomain/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/~1089811.1135986/htdocs/logon.php"

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the reason it did not work is because our host network solutions is using a proxy for SSL so anything server side that detects protocol will not work and typically results in a loop.